# Extending Collection in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to extend my model collections in Laravel. I'm following these two tutorials here that say I just need to override the `newCollection` method. Seems pretty straight forward enough, but it seems the `newCollection` method is not firing.

I'm using Laravel 4.2.

[link1](http://www.neontsunami.com/posts/diffing-eloquent-collections-in-laravel-4)

[link2](http://heera.it/extend-laravel-eloquent-collection-object#.VBjX9_mSwQM)

My Model:

```
class City extends Eloquent {

    public function newCollection(array $models = Array())
    {
        echo 'here';
        return new Extensions\CityCollection($models);
    }
}
```

Custom Collection:

```
<?php namespace Extensions;

echo 'here';

class CityCollection extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {

    public function findInList($name)
    {
        foreach ($this as $city)
        {
            if (strtolower($city->name) === strtolower($name))
            {
                return $city;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

None of the `echo` statements are firing. Am I doing something wrong? I've also run a dump-autoload and have added the containing folder to my `composer.json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was about to delete, but maybe this will help someone in the future. It turns out I just needed to flush my models cache.